# Why is Access search field sometimes returning first entry in table?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'm maintaining an Access DB (the client is using Access 2016, 64bit) and sometimes a user is reporting that when they search for a record, the search keeps returning the first record in the table instead of the record searched for.

The database is split, there are about 2 dozen users at any given time.  The backend is stored on a file server, the frontend is copied to each user's desktop each time they log in via GPO.  Some users are remote, some in office connected to local ethernet.  This problem only seems to impact one user whether they are remote or in-office.

The code for the search field (unbound combobox) is below, in general users will search for a record and select it from the combobox to open it in the form:

```
Private Sub cmbGoToRecord_AfterUpdate()
    
    If Me.Dirty = True Then
        If CheckForCompleteness = False Then Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Me.cmbGoToRecordCustomerName = ""
    
    Dim rs As Object
    
    Me.Detail.Visible = False
    
    Set rs = Me.Recordset.Clone
    
    If Len(Me.cmbGoToRecord & vbNullString) > 0 Then
        rs.FindFirst "[CustomerID] = " & Me.cmbGoToRecord
        If Not rs.EOF Then Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
    End If
    
    If Len(Me.cmbGoToRecord & vbNullString) = 0 Then
        Set rs = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set rs = Nothing
    
    Me.Detail.Visible = True
    
    End Sub
```

The `CheckForCompleteness` is a function that checks whether certain fields are filled out or not, if they are not a message box pops up instructing the user to fill them out, the user cannot save or navigate from that record until it is completed.

The `Me.Detail.Visible` changes were implemented because users wanted a visible cue that something was happening.

There are 2 search fields (1 for name and the other is for customer ID), I blank the other field out.  The code for that search field is the same as above, just the combobox name is different.

I am not able to replicate this issue on the clients system, and I cannot replicate it on our in-house test environment.  I suspect a network issue but I don't have the means to test that at the client's location.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.NoMatch`:

```vb
Private Sub cmbGoToRecord_AfterUpdate()
    
    If Me.Dirty = True Then
        If CheckForCompleteness = False Then Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Me.cmbGoToRecordCustomerName = ""
    
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    
    Me.Detail.Visible = False
    
    Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
    
    If Len(Me.cmbGoToRecord & vbNullString) > 0 Then
        rs.FindFirst "[CustomerID] = " & Me.cmbGoToRecord
        If Not rs.NoMatch Then
            Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
        End If
    End If
    rs.Close

    Set rs = Nothing
    
    Me.Detail.Visible = True
    
End Sub
```